# How to prevent Misfit from informing about failed syncs in Pebble?

Tags: android

I am using Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9506 (Android 5.0.1 with kernel 3.4.0-6069869) and [MisFit](https://sso.misfit.com/auth/login) v3.3 with Pebble Classic (firmware v. 2.9.1, hardware V3R3). 
I receive many failed syncs daily. 
I would like prevent them from occurring. 
I think the problem is in the both products: the software *Misfit* and *Pebble* because

- Pebble does not allow you to prevent applications giving you vibrations about. I would like customize which applications can do what.
- Misfit does not allow you to disable informing about failed syncs.

I think Android community cannot do much here because Pebble is working externally from it. 
I sent already messages to Misfit support and Pebble support with the link to this thread.
I will let you know when this is solved and what are possible alternatives if it is not solved. I think the selection of such an app which does not disturb you is an alternative, since the release of updates in the Pebble firmware is slow.

How can you prevent failed syncs in Misfit of Pebble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connot. Misfit does not want to give the control of some warnings away. They insist in keeping the capability about informing all warnings themselves. They just answer that they try to avoid such a situation but will not give away such a control such as warning the user about interruptions.